# Using "was" or "were" for proper noun "Northern Plains"

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, proper-nouns

I want to use the phrase "Northern Plains" in a sentence as follows:

*"The Northern Plains **were** a place of great danger; people never went there alone."*

Is "were" (plural) the correct form, or do I need to use "was" because the Northern Plains is a single specific place (proper noun)? Or is it just a stylistic choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stylistic choice, for example in the Wikipedia article on The "[Great Plains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Plains)", a singular verb is used at first:

> The Great Plains [...] is a broad expanse of flatland in North America.

> The Great Plains lies across both Central United States and Western Canada

However later, the article switches:

> The Great Plains are the westernmost portion of the vast North American Interior Plains

> The Great Plains consist of a broad stretch of country...